# Closing a winform App when interop word exits

Tags: c#, winforms-interop

I'm working on a winform application which opens a new word doc each time a button is pressed and closes the older one. The question is: How can I make the winform application quits if the user closes the MS Word Application not the document? I tried `word_DocumentBeforeClose()` but it occurs when  either the word application or the word document is closed.

This is the code I'm using:

```
wordDocument.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges); 
word.DocumentBeforeClose += new ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeCloseEventHandler(word_DocumentBeforeClose);
wordDocument = word.Documents.Open(FileName);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried hooking onto the [`word.Quit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationevents2_event.quit.aspx) event?